# How to close the keyboard on tapping anywhere outside the dialog below in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mobile-application

[image]

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity

    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                    })
                }
                .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp),
            shadowElevation = 4.dp
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As your question is currently written, it is hard to give you help. Please edit your question and add some details about what you want to achieve and most importantly what you have tried already. Also, have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

inside onDismiss you can handle that

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current


onDismissRequest = { onDismiss()
 keyboardController?.hide()
focusManager.clear() },
```

Inside Column
use

```
Column(
modifier = Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTapGestures(onTap = {
keyboardController?.hide()
focusManager.clear()
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: This does not make a difference when tapping anywhere in the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Since, the dialog has its own LocalFocusManager moving the focusManager inside the dialog scope made it work for me.

The code goes like this:

```
Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
    ) {
        val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp),
            shadowElevation = 4.dp
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                        localFocusManager.clearFocus()
                    })
                }
                    .padding(24.dp)
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                )
```